# Minecraft 1.10.2 skins are not showing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok. Whenever I go on a server, any server, nobody's skins show up. This has been happening since I made my account and its super annoying. My friends skins won't show up, mine won't. Everyone is just Alex or Steve. I haven't been able to google a fix because nobody else has experienced this. I know if I ask for help none of the answers will work but this is worth the shot. So if anybody could help fix this it would mean so much.

Comment: What version of MC are you using? This seems to happen after updating to 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

The textures servers are currently down at the moment. Your skins won't show till they are up.

If you go to [this link](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/), you will be able to find the server status.